# Bad instruction error for indexPath Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, exc-bad-instruction

i'm making an app that needs to transfer data using segues and cells. I have two nearly identical View Controllers but one of them is getting the following error on line 3 whenever I launch it:

[image: Bad Instruction Error]

I know that Bad Instruction errors mean that it is finding nil, but I don't know how to fix it. This is the code that isn't working:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: InstrumentTableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? InstrumentTableCell
        cell.configurateTheCell(recipies[indexPath.row])

        return cell!
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: We need to know the line of the error.

Comment: First of all, use the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to get always a valid cell and get rid of the optional dance. Second of all, is the class of the custom cell set to `InstrumentTableCell` in Interface Builder?

Comment: thanks vadian, that worked!